# Backing up app data from two different devices to the same iCloud account

Tags: ios, icloud, backup

Let's say I have an app that can back up to iCloud Drive, like WhatsApp, on iPhone #1. I back it up to iCloud Drive. However, if I have the same app, WhatsApp, on iPhone #2 which is connected to the same iCloud account, will I be able to back it up to iCloud Drive as well, or will my #1 backup be overwritten?

Comment: What steps do you take on iPhone 1 to back up what's app? The answer hinges upon if you are talking about iCloud backup of the device or if the app does backup to iCloud Drive within the app itself.

Comment: @bmike it's backs up to iCloud Drive. There also is the device backup in addition to that as you said. The problem is, I can't view the files – app backups to iCloud Drive – from any other device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The backup will be overwritten.

Your Apple ID is what's used to sync data between devices.  It will take the most-recent change as what should be backed-up.  iCloud will *think* that you want the most-recent change to be shared across devices and it will populate that change to all devices with that same Apple ID.

The way around this would be to use Dropbox or something similar as the backup.  That way you can specify separate folders for the backup and prevent one from overwriting the other.

Comment: I assume that there is no way to back WhatsApp to Dropbox, even manually, right? As far as I can tell, it's not possible to move app data backed up to iCloud Drive to anywhere, even on a Mac.

Comment: I can access my iCloud Drive from Finder and see the separate folders for each of the apps I'm backing-up there.  I haven't tried it but theoretically, you should be able to set your Dropbox backup to point at a specific folder in iCloud Drive and back that up.  Maybe someone here has tried that?